# Creating an entity service with different views/sights depending on user's rights

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject-2

For a custom blog implementation (written in ASP.NET MVC 3), I wrote a `PostService` class implementing an `IPostService` interface that is retrieving `Post` entities representing blog posts. However, not every post is visible by default; the property `IsPublished` distinguishes between published blog posts and saved drafts. On the blog's landing page, I would like to display a list of the five latest posts. Of course, only published posts are supposed to appear there.

There are several different places in code where an implementation of `IPostService` is injected into the corresponding constructor by Ninject 2, e.g. for a class listing the monthly post archives etc. In my administration area, the service is supposed to return all blog posts including drafts. On the blog itself, the service is always supposed to only deal with published posts.

Where do I configure whether to include unpublished posts in the `RetrieveAll` method of `IPostService`? To me, that sounds like a dependency container injection issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you add two methods to your service RetrieveAll, RetrievePublished and let the controller decide what it wants to display?

Comment: Thanks — that's exactly what I did some days ago.